# resizing window with gridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am stuck on this a large amount of time and I dont know how to do it, despite seraching on Google lots of times. My problem is that, I have a program, with a container obtained from the JFrame. The thing is, I put my menuBar correctly, and just below my two buttons, but when I maximize the window, it appears a annoying white space that I dont want to be there. If i dont maximize the window, the components are fine placed, like this:

[image]

But when I maximize the window, it appears that annoying space (the one marked in red):

[image]

And what I want is that the MenuBar  and the buttons, stays stuck in that corner like the first picture. The code of the gridbaglayout of the menu bar and the buttons is the following:

```
//MenuBar
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.weightx = 0.5;
    gbc.weighty = 0.0; // si no ponemos esto la barra NO se queda anclada en la esquina
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;

    //gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    //gbc.gridwidth = 2; 
    //gbc.gridheight = 1;
    menuBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    pane.add(menuBar, gbc);
//buttons
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;//reseteamos su valor 
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER; // con esto indicamos que va a ser el ultimo componente de esa fila
    gbc.weightx = 0.0;
    gbc.weighty = 0.0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black)); //luego quitar es para ver lo que ocupaba el panel
    pane.add(panel, gbc);
```

Comment: Quit wasting peoples time by reposting question. You were given the answer in your last question. You have completely ignored the advice given and the exact same advice has be repeated here. You were given a link to the Swing tutorial on how to use menus so you could read the tutorial and copy the demo code and experiment.

Answer (score 0):

```
pane.add(menuBar, gbc);
```

That's not how you add a `JMenuBar`, you add it using [`JFrame#setMenuBar(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setMenuBar(java.awt.MenuBar)). For example:

```
frame.setMenuBar(menuBar);
```

Then the buttons should arrange as desired

Comment: thanks, it works partially. I mean the JMenuBar is stucked in the corner, but the buttons not,  and another thing, why jmenubar is added in that way? why i cant add it to a container?

Comment: You can add it to a container but what users are used to is having the `JMenuBar` at the top of the windows, not in the middle. But you can add them. For the buttons, provide a proper [mcve] as is we cannot provide full help. Remove all unnecessary code not related to the question such as images, ActionListeners, etc, and just create a simple GUI with both `JButton`s and the `JMenuBar` so we can replicate your issue and help you fix it. Can you also provide an image of how you want the buttons to be placed after resizing? @victor26567

Comment: Also, as per the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) that's the correct way to add the `JMenuBar` to a `JFrame` @victor26567

Comment: This advice and tutorial link was already provided in the OP's previous question on this topic hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510303/positioning-buttons-below-menu-bar-with-gridbaglayout Just thought I'd let you know so you don't waste any more time,

Comment: Cool, thanks @camickr that reminds me to check low rep users' profiles to check for things like these before answering tho...